# Is there a good way of including additional files with ansible?

Tags: ansible

Sa I have a project like this:

```
/roles
  some-role/
    files/
      configuration-files/
         rule1.xml
         rule2.xml
         rule3.xml
my-playbook.yml
```

Say the role is installed via ansible-galaxy and I want to include `rule4.xml` without manipulating the role. Where would I put it and how would I include it?

Answer (score 0):

If your point is about "extending" the role, just create another role that will handle the diferences (e.g. `file4.xml`) like `some-role-my-purpose`, add a dependency in `some-role-my-purpose/meta/main.yml` to `some-role` and that should be all.

If `file4.xml` has a general interest, send a pull request to `some-role`.

Sidenote: I would really think twice before using galaxy roles to build my infrastructure. Roles are really small, the `added_value_of_change/screwed_by_change` ratio is very low. You're better of forking the ones you like and start from here to control change.